# Why execve hang

Tags: c++11, fork, exec

I have a struct storing `file`, `argv`, and `envp` in C++ STL containers. The struct also has methods that transform them to c-style pointers for `execve` call.

```
struct Foo {
  std::string file;
  std::vector <std::string> argv;
  std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> envp;

  inline auto c_file() const;
  inline auto c_argv() const;
  inline auto c_envp() const;
}

// Function: c_file
inline auto Foo::c_file() const {
  return file.c_str();
}

// Function: c_argv
inline auto Foo::c_argv() const {

  auto ptr = std::make_unique<char*[]>(argv.size() + 1);
  for(size_t i=0; i<argv.size(); ++i) {
    ptr[i] = const_cast<char*>(argv[i].c_str());
  }
  ptr[argv.size()] = nullptr;

  return ptr;
}

// Function: c_envp
inline auto Foo::c_envp() const {

  std::unique_ptr<char*, std::function<void(char**)>> ptr(
    new char*[envp.size() + 1],
    [sz=envp.size()+1](char** ptr) {
      for(size_t i=0; i<sz; ++i) {
        delete [] ptr[i];
      }
      delete [] ptr;
    }
  );

  auto idx = size_t{0};

  for(const auto& kvp : envp) {
    auto entry = kvp.first + "=" + kvp.second;
    ptr.get()[idx] = new char[entry.size() + 1];
    ::strncpy(ptr.get()[idx], entry.c_str(), entry.size() + 1);
    ++idx;
  }
  ptr.get()[idx] = nullptr;

  return ptr;
}
```

In my program, I use the following way to call `execve`.

```
void in_parent_process(const Foo& foo) {
  char stack[1024*1024];
  ::clone(child_entry, stack + 1024*1024, myflags, &foo)
}

void child_entry(void* ptr) {
  const auto& foo = *static_cast<Foo*>(ptr);
  ::execve(foo.c_file(), foo.c_argv().get(), foo.c_envp().get());
}
```

However, the call to `execve` sometimes hang without any response. This makes my parent process fail to synchronize with the child process (through a pipe close-on-exec). Is there anything wrong with my idea here of using `unique_ptr`? Or there is something wrong with my understanding about setting the stack to the `clone` call?

Comment: Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what is happenning... I can't believe that `execve` is hanging.

Comment: Also `clone` is mostly for *implementors* of multi-threading libraries like [nptl(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html) so is not friendly with C++11 threads (which use pthreads). I recommend never using `clone`

Comment: Your megabyte `stack` automatic variable array smells really bad

Comment: I need to create Linux container with clone. Without clone, how could I make it?

Comment: But did you use `strace`? Also, when `execve` fails, it continues, so you should use `perror` (or something better, logging `errno`...) after it. At last, why don't you use *existing* containerization machinery (e.g. Docker) or at least study carefully their source code (they are free software)?

Answer (score 0):

> Or there is something wrong with my understanding about setting the stack to the clone call?

Yes, your code is wrong. You are misusing [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) by passing as the stack zone some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) which sits in your current [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (so gets invalidated as soon as the calling function returns; this is typical [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). But that stack zone should generally be the result of some [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or at least, some [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)) and should not be part of the calling thread's call stack.

And I think you should not use `clone` since it is already used by [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) (which is also used by C++11 threads on Linux)

As I commented, you should use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) for debugging (notably to understand what happens when "the call to execve sometimes hang"). Also, when [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) fails, it returns and continues, so you should use `perror` (or something better, logging `errno`...) after it. Otherwise `execve` was successful and reinitialize your process (including its entire [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)) to run the new program.  At last, why don't you use *existing* containerization machinery (e.g. Docker) or at least study carefully their source code (they are free software)?

> the call to execve sometimes hang without any response

BTW, `execve` is a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). So it either succeeds without returning (by reinitializing your process to start a new program) or it fails quickly (and `execve` returns only on failure).  In either case, `execve` is done by the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) in a few milliseconds at most. so I can't imagine how it could "hang". Hence, **`execve` cannot hang** by itself.

<sup>(in other words, it is not `execve` which hangs but something else)</sup>

You need to **add error handling after `execve`**, at least with

```
void child_entry(void* ptr) {
 const auto& foo = *static_cast<Foo*>(ptr);
 ::execve(foo.c_file(), foo.c_argv().get(), foo.c_envp().get());
 perror("execve");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and you might replace the `perror("execve");` with something more verbose like `perror((std::string{"execve of "}+foo.c_file()).c_str());`; you could also consider using [_exit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) instead of [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) but then you probably should flush your buffered IO (e.g. using [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)...)

You may also want to use logging facilities, see [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html).

Be aware of the [PATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (you could query it in your [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) using [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) as `getenv("PATH")`...); maybe you want [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) instead of `execve`.